# ASP.Net / Umbraco Website has (initially) very high server response time

Tags: asp.net, lazy-loading, umbraco, pageload

I've got this problem.
I launched an ASP.NET website with the Umbraco CMS on an ISP.
(Its just a very basic informative site. nothing special.)

When I go want to visit the website however, the *first pageload takes a lot of time*, sometimes even up to 20 seconds. Of course this is ridiculous. 
Afterwards, I am able to navigate the site relatively quick..

So every first pageload is slow, then everything is OK, more or less.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem could be? Would it be IIS? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIS is probably configured to shutdown the application pool after N minutes of inactivity.

AFAIK, this is the default behaviour on IIS.

Comment: Actually this is standard operating procedure at a lot of hosts where there are shared sites.  A vast majority of sites are simply not visited.  Because of this hosts can usually offload them from memory.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the first request to be served, IIS at least starts the APP Pool. This might take a bit of a time. Maybe Umbraco loads initially some data, but I did not have any experience with Umbraco, so that's beyond my knowledge.

-sa

Comment: Is it to do with the xml caching of all the content on first load?

Comment: Would IIS have to restart the App pool everytime on a regular ISP?

Comment: It could be the xmlcaching, I dont know, but point is, Normally Umbraco doesnt load so slow.  So it wouldnt seem the solution to me.

Comment: Usually the app pool get restarted if you change some config or binary files, after a time of inactivity. If nothing of this occurred then you might verify if this is the correct track this by writing a log entry when the app starts (Global.Asax.cs)

Answer (score 0):

What do you meen by first page load?

Have you just done a build? If this is a website then .Net will compile and load the dll. Then IIS will cache page outputs.

Do you have any large images on the page?

Essentially there are an infinate number of reasons. Have you used firebug? Determine where the loadtime is?

Do you have a link?

Comment: By first page load I mean, everytime I start up my browser and navigate to the website (www.interesita.nl).
I doesnt have anything to with images or anything. The page stays blank for the 20seconds orso. So I think the server responce time is slow, but any other websites on this ISP load normal.

Comment: Have you tried using firebug to confirm the load time is on the server?

Comment: I just did, the load time is on server I guess. Could you check and look at the outcome of the headers? I dont know how to interpret it. it's about www.interesita.nl.
thanks in advance..

Comment: 1st Hit took 1.4s - No problem there!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into a keep alive service. There are many available that regularly poll you site to keep the application pool running and prevent the startup delay you are seeing. More information [here](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/103.aspx) and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838318/how-to-keep-asp-net-assemblies-in-appdomain-alive/838348)