# Prevent WCF Service AppDomain from being unloaded

Tags: wcf, iis, appdomain

We have a WCF service that we would like to remain "long lived". For whatever reason though, IIS seems to be unloading our AppDomain whenever we are idle for ~20 minutes.

I can attach a method to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload` event, is there any way to cancel the unload in code? Or perhaps a configuration in IIS that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course I just found another question with what is presumably the answer:
[How to keep ASP.NET assemblies in AppDomain alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838318/how-to-keep-asp-net-assemblies-in-appdomain-alive)

I had looked at all the settings for recycling AppPools, but missed the vital "Idle Timeout" property.
Its default is of course 20 minutes and it can be changed to zero to stop this behaviour.